# I am getting this error - Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option

Tags: android-viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

I am getting the above mentioned error. can someone help in resolving this error?

[image: this is my view model provider factory class][image: this is my view model class][image: this is my DAO class]